# How can I debug $PATH?

Tags: macos, bash

There is a directory in my $PATH that I want removed.
But I cannot figure out how it got there.
I've looked at all the places I can think of where $PATH gets set: .profile, .bashrc, .bash_profile, et cetra
but I cannot find who is putting this particular directory into $PATH.
Clearly, I do not know all the things that change $PATH when my system starts.
Is there a way to debug the startup sequence?
Ideally I just want to set a trap on anything that touches $PATH.
Or may there is a log file (or ordered set of log files) I can scan.
How can I find how each directory gets set in $PATH among all the things that run when my system starts?

Comment: `There is a directory in my $PATH that I want removed` why don't you edit your path and then export it..?

Comment: Did you check the system startup files in `/etc` (such as `/etc/bashrc`)? You could edit the startup scripts and have each echo the current path, before and after, to get an idea where it's happening. It might yield a clue.

Comment: Look also at `/etc/profile`, etc. Find the list of files that are loaded: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.)](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about programming.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try running `bash --login -x`, then try to identify from the output where the include files are coming from.

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Try `bash --login -x` in a terminal window. This will print every line of the setup scripts as they are executed (kudos go to [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro)).

   Alternatively, you could add `set -x` near the top of `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.profile`. The danger here is that if you make a mistake, your system may become unusable (if you can't start a new shell anymore) plus you need to be `root`. If you want to try this, I suggest to create two terminal windows, keep them open at all cost, make the changes and then start new terminal windows to see the effects.
2. Use `grep -r PATTERN /` (replace `PATTERN` with the path that you look for). That should search your whole hard disk for this pattern and can take a long time. Maybe start with your home directory. If you want to search just the `.` files, use this trick: `grep -r PATTERN .??*`

Comment: `bash --login -x` doesn't just have the same effect, though. It doesn't require root privileges or run the risk of breaking shell invocation.

Comment: @kojiro: I don't have a Mac, so I can't test this. I'm waiting for confirmation.

Comment: @kojiro and @Aaron\ Digjull -- Thank you for these answers the combination of the two helped. The `bash --login -x` does not show you the filename the errant command is in. But it did show me the PATTERN where my problem was getting set. So I used the `grep -r PATTERN .??*` to isolate the errant file. It should be pointed out that this command can take a long time to run if you file system is larger and it will likely report many unrelated errors (mostly: `No such file or directory`)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using BASH, the way the login loading works is this order:

- `/etc/profile` is first read in.
- `$HOME/.bash_profile` is read in.
- If `$HOME/.bash_profile` doesn't exist, then `$HOME/.bash_login` is read in.
- If `$HOME/.bash_login` doesn't exist, then `$HOME/.profile` is read in.

***NOTE***: That `$HOME/.bashrc` is not read in by default. However, many people do *source* in their `.bashrc` file at login.

When a shell is invoked, and it's not a login shell, then the `$HOME/.bashrc` file is loaded.

---

By default, the Mac's PATH is `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. This is set via `/etc/profile` which executes `/usr/libexec/path_helper`. This takes the initial paths from `/etc/paths.d/...` and from `/etc/paths`. The `/etc/paths.d` only adds in the `/opt/X11/bin` directory if X11 is installed. Otherwise, `/etc/paths` is used and it contains the default paths.

Mine is set to:

- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/bin`
- `/usr/sbin`
- `/sbin`

I use `/usr/local/bin` for third party tools. or newer versions of already installed tools. For example, `/usr/bin/svn` is version 1.7.17 while `/usr/local/bin/svn` is set to version 1.8.10. Me invoking `svn` will invoke the version of Subversion I installed, and not the native version.

In this case, the 1.8 version of Subversion is actually installed in `/opt/subversion/bin/svn`, but I create a symbolic link to it in `/usr/local/svn`. I do this for any tool that I install: The tool gets installed in `/opt` and I link the binaries and scripts to `/usr/local/bin`, so they're in my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Place these 2 lines **at top** of your `~/.bash_profile` (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
set -o functrace
trap '[[ "$BASH_COMMAND" == *" PATH="* ]] && echo "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
```

Then exit the current shell and start a new shell.

**It will print every time `PATH` variable is set in your environment.**

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)

Comment: Thanks ! It works ! Any chance we can also make it print a bit of context? the `trap` manual section is quite big

Comment: In `echo` command you can print whatever you think is good like `env` or `history`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it took 9 years to answer. Indeed, finding out where some part is defined requires too much effort.

Thus, I’ve codified the heuristics into a tool:

https://github.com/d-led/pathdebug

```
pathdebug PATH
```

the tool makes a best-effort attempt at looking at known locations to find out where the path is set.

[image: path locations]